# Is it possible to do live modifications on Visual Studio Code itself?

Tags: visual-studio-code, scripting

Like in Emacs where I can define an interactive function and it's instantly available as a command.

Or write and run a small script which does multiple operations on the current file.

These are very useful in Emacs. Is the same possible with vscode? Can it be scriptable?

After all, it's a Javascript program AFAIK, so there should be a way to do these on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

You can write an extension that watches a file. Then it makes whatever command you define in that file available in the command bar.